# Add cookies to firefox with java

Tags: java, firefox, cookies

I want to add a Cookie with java to firefox. But I don't know how to do it. I dont want to use a servlet either. Is there a way to do this without a servlet.
Java should add a Cookie to firefox with the name JEB2, the content: 123dasdhui2398 and the domain: .banner.t-online.com.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to run Java ? What do you have ? An applet ? An app ? A webserver ? Something else ? Be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie object in java is part of servlet api (javax.servlet.http.Cookie). 
Browser reads cookies from response. So as far as I can tell you must generate some POST/GET request from your browser to some URL and this URL must response to you with response containing some cookie. The simplest and i think only way to do this is by writing some serwlet.

Another way (I dont know if this is possible) is to talk with firefox API directly. Look at selenium project (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/)